# Using hash key and sort from DynamoDB in Redis

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-elasticache

I have DynamoDB table with

HASH Key `item_id` and sort key `timestamp`

Then another local secondary index with
HASH key ''user_id`and sort key`timestamp`

I have to make 100s of millions of read-requests per day to DynamoDB. That will be very costly.

I am thinking of using Amazon ElastiCache as then read all the stuff from there.

But I am not sure if I can query Redis the same way like I do for DynamoDB like

`query(item_id = '32323232' and timestamp > 42343875453)`

will I be able to do that in Redis?

Comment: Did you check RediSearch?

Comment: @GuyKorland can DAX work as redis ? how much will be cost diff

Comment: As far as I know DAX can't, if you're looking for managed solution with RediSearch you need Redis Cloud Pro https://redislabs.com/redis-enterprise/pro/

Comment: DAX will accelerate your performance with an in-memory cache. You can continue to use the same DynamoDB API. You can find [pricing info here](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/provisioned/#.E2.80.A2_DynamoDB_Accelerator_.28DAX.29)